# Socket.io Send message to specific client on one namespace if same socket has multiple namespace

Tags: node.js, sockets, namespaces, socket.io

I have two socket.io namespace:
Public and Private

Each client is connected to Public namespace
and Authenticated clients can connect to Private namespace.

I am maintaining a array of sockets for client connected to Private namespace like:

```
var socketarray = [socket object,socket object];
```

now If i emit a message on perticular socket from above array that message is going to both of Public and Private  namespaces(because same client is connected on Public namespace too) but i want that message to be sent to Private namespace only

```
socketarray[0].emit('message',{test});
```

Comment: In your application on the client-side are you setting up listeners specifically for the private and public namespaces separately?

Comment: yup i am settings the listeners for both private and public on client side